# Chromatic Index in Graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

There is a graph $G$ with maximum degree that is greater than $0$. Suppose that $G$ contains a perfect matching $P$ and that $G-P$ (graph after removing all edges of $P$ in $G$) is bipartite. What is now the chromatic index(edge chromatic number) of $G$ in terms of it's maximum degree? I'm not really sure how to approach this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know the fact that bipartite graphs always have chromatic index equal to their maximum degree? Also, the first hypothesis there is a bit superfluous; if $G$ has a perfect matching, then its maximum degree is certainly bigger than $0$.

Comment: Yes that's correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(New) Hint: The edges of a bipartite graph may be colored with $\Delta$ colors (where $\Delta$ is the maximum degree).

Comment: In this case, a bipartite graph is not 2-colorable since I am trying to find the chromatic index (edge chromatic number)